# Switch device driver from UAS to usb-storage using unbind/bind

Tags: drivers, usb-drive

Sometimes the `UAS` driver for Linux is buggy and I need to use the `usb-storage`. In the past, I've done this by putting an entry in `/etc/modprobe.d` specifying quirks for the SATA/USB cable connecting the drive, but this requires a reboot every time I want to switch.

I've tried unbinding the device from the `UAS` driver and rebinding it to `usb-storage` but when rebinding I get the `write error: No such device`.

(The `unbind` command does succeed and I use the exact same bus ID for the binding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's impossible without setting the quirks. The source code for the `usb-storage` driver always checks first is `UAS` is supported, and if so returns with the `-ENXIO` error code - Device not found.

It seems like the other way also won't work - to blacklist `UAS` but manually bind to it when required, because it also checks for the `UAS` blacklist flag.

**However**, it seems like you **can** change the quirks at runtime, so you can unbind the `UAS` driver then

```
$ echo "0bc2:ab38:u" > /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks
```

replacing `0bc2:ab38` with the VID:PID of your device (you can check via `lsusb` et. al.) and then try to bind to the `usb-storage` driver.

Comment: Might be useful to note that you can check if this worked by looking in the kernel log with `tail -n 20 -f /var/log/kern.log`. If sucessful, after connecting the device, there should be a line saying `UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead`. Also, if you want to revert this later, just do `echo "" > /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks`.